# Convergence when $|a_n - a| <\epsilon^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers, $a$ also real.  Suppose that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, we know that there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n -a|<\epsilon^2$

Does $a_n$ converge to $a$? What about in more general settings, when we are dealing with functions?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Fix $\tilde \varepsilon>0$ then choose $\varepsilon^2 < \tilde \varepsilon$ and apply the above statement.

Comment: Regarding your question about  "more general settings", I think that this is the statement you're looking for: if $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is such that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 0$ and a sequence is such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n - a|  < f(\epsilon)$, then it indeed the case that $a_n$ converges to $a$.

Comment: I suppose you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x) =0$! @Ben Grossman.

Comment: @diracsum Exactly, silly typo

Comment: Thanks for the answers! That general theorem you provided is quite insightful! You could also do a substitution argument I think, namley, note that $\sqrt x$ is a surjective function, then let $\sqrt \alpha>0$, and then apply the given condition, get $|a_n-a|<\alpha$

Comment: Side note: be careful when using exclamation mark after numbers. It can be interpreted as factorial.